# Preventing FsCheck from generating NaN and infinities

Tags: testing, f#, floating-point, generator, fscheck

I have a deeply nested datastructure with floats all over the place.
I'm using FsCheck to check if the data is unchanged after serializing and then deserializing.

This property fails, when a float is either NaN or +/- infinity, however, such a case doesn't interest me, since I don't expect these values to occur in the actual data.

Is there a way to prevent FsCheck from generating NaN and infinities?

I have tried discarding generated data that contains said values, but this makes the test incredibly slow, so slow in fact, that the test is still running while I'm writing this, and I have my doubts it will actually finish...

Comment: Use the `NormalFloat` wrapper https://github.com/fsharp/FsCheck/blob/master/src/FsCheck/Arbitrary.fs#L28 https://github.com/fsharp/FsCheck/blob/master/src/FsCheck/Arbitrary.fs#L603

Comment: Oh, cool. So, how do I do this? :-)

Comment: Make your test parameters of type `NormalFloat`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get what you're trying to say.
The data that should be generated is a record of records of records (sorta), some of which contains floats among other stuff. I would like all places where floats should be generated, to not use NaN or infinities.

Comment: Did you write your own generator for this data or are you using the built-in reflection-based generator?

Comment: I've got the same problems as @Phazyck. In my code the from<int> doesn't work. All the features in FsCheck are so convoluted and undocumented, so the entry barrier to use this framework is very high. E.g. I wrote a generator to create even numbers. I then made Arbitrary<int> with it, but it doesn't work. Please make it simpler and better documented. We don't need more features now, we need more examples and docs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For reflectively generated types that contain floats (as I suspect you're using) you can overwrite the default generator for floats by writing a class as follows:

```
type Overrides() =
    static member Float() =
        Arb.Default.Float()
        |> filter (fun f -> not <| System.Double.IsNaN(f) &&
                            not <| System.Double.IsInfinity(f))
```

And then calling:

```
Arb.register<Overrides>()
```

Before FsCheck tries to generate the types; e.g. in your test setup or before calling Check.Quick.

You can check the result of the register method to see how it merged the default arbitrary instances with the new ones; it should have overridden them.

If you are using the xUnit extension you can avoid calling the Arb.register by using the Arbitraries argument of PropertyAttribute:

```
[<Property(Arbitraries=Overides)>]
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding on your last paragraph with an example of how that would be done?

Answer (score 8):

As Mauricio Scheffer said, you can use NormalFloat type in test parameter.

Simple example for list of floats:

```
open FsCheck

let f (x : float list) = x |> List.map id

let propFloat (x : float list) = x = (f x)

let propNormalFloat (xn : NormalFloat list) = 
    let x = xn |> List.map NormalFloat.get
    x = f x

Check.Quick propFloat
//Falsifiable, after 18 tests (13 shrinks) (StdGen (761688149,295892075)):
//[nan]

Check.Quick propNormalFloat
//Ok, passed 100 tests.
```

Comment: I guess this could work in other cases, such as those you illustrate. Problem is, the data is not simply a list of float or something like that, that allows my to write NormalFloat as part of the type, but a more complex structure that contains floats in all kinds of places, but also other types as well. What I need is to have FsCheck to generate NormalFloats in any place a float is needed, no matter how the data looks, as Kurt Schelfthout show. :-)